# Does Youtube New Terms of Service & Developer Policies 10th, 2017 affects previously playing video

Tags: android-youtube-api

I am unable to load video that was working previously in my youtube player api for android, does it is due to this new policy..

Comment: pls refer http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before posting your query

Comment: in the same situation... please can anyone shed some light on the subject?